# How to correctly perform group by on max timestamp?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I am using `MySQL 5.7.38` version.
I have the below query which is returning the correct sample data as below:

```
SELECT
   t.r_id,
   t.hostname,
   t.a_tmstamp,
   max(t.r_status) as r_status,
   max(t.message) as message,
   max(t.m_id) as m_id
FROM (
SELECT
   audit.r_id as r_id,
   nhost.host_name as hostname,
   meta.r_status as r_status,   
   meta.step as step,
   meta.id as m_id,
   meta.message as message,
   audit.a_timestamp as a_tmstamp,
   npr.nas_provider as nas_provider             
FROM audit
   INNER JOIN npr ON npr.nr_id = audit.r_id
   AND audit.a_timestamp BETWEEN now() - interval 30 DAY AND now()
   INNER JOIN nhost ON audit.r_id = nhost.nr_id      
   INNER JOIN meta ON audit.audit_m_id = meta.id                                  
   INNER JOIN nprw ON npr.pw_id = nprw.id   
   AND nprw.ap_step = meta.step                
   WHERE meta.r_status regexp 'FAIL'
   ORDER BY  a_timestamp DESC
     ) AS t 
 GROUP BY t.r_id, t.hostname, t.a_tmstamp
 ORDER BY a_tmstamp DESC;
```

Sample Data:

```
+-----------+----------+-----------------------+--------------+------------+---------+
| r_id      | hostname | a_tmstamp             |  r_status    |  message   |  m_id   |
+-----------+----------------------------------+--------------+------------+---------+
| a1ffadc9  | abc01    | 6/9/2022  6:15:17 PM  | PROGRESS     |  message1  | d759df3 |
| a1ffadc9  | abc02    | 6/9/2022  6:15:17 PM  | PROGRESS     |  message2  | d759df3 |
| a1ffadc9  | abc01    | 6/9/2022  6:14:17 PM  | PROGRESS     |  null      | fdb2f19 |
| a1ffadc9  | abc02    | 6/9/2022  6:14:17 PM  | PROGRESS     |  null      | fdb2f19 |
| 246cc315  | cad01    | 6/9/2022  4:43:52 PM  | FAILED       |  message3  | f5435f0 |
| 246cc315  | cad02    | 6/9/2022  4:43:52 PM  | FAILED       |  message4  | f5435f0 |
| 258e55ac  | cad01    | 6/9/2022  4:42:52 PM  | FAILED       |  reason1   | 432ca62 |
| 258e55ac  | cad02    | 6/9/2022  4:42:52 PM  | FAILED       |  reason2   | 432ca62 |
+-----------+----------+-----------------------+--------------+------------+---------+
```

How can I perform group by on `max(t.a_tmstamp)` so that I get below output?

Desired Output:

```
+-----------+----------+-----------------------+--------------+------------+---------+
| r_id      | hostname | a_tmstamp             |  r_status    |  message   |  m_id   |
+-----------+----------------------------------+--------------+------------+---------+
| a1ffadc9  | abc01    | 6/9/2022  6:15:17 PM  | PROGRESS     |  message1  | d759df3 |
| a1ffadc9  | abc02    | 6/9/2022  6:15:17 PM  | PROGRESS     |  message2  | d759df3 |
| 246cc315  | cad01    | 6/9/2022  4:43:52 PM  | FAILED       |  message3  | f5435f0 |
| 246cc315  | cad02    | 6/9/2022  4:43:52 PM  | FAILED       |  message4  | f5435f0 |
+-----------+----------+-----------------------+--------------+------------+---------+
```

Comment: unclear what version you mean; what does `select version();` show?

Comment: 5.7.38-log is the version

Comment: what type is audit.a_timestamp?

Comment: audit.a_timestamp is of type `DATETIME(3)`

Comment: Are you sure the query return that result? It doesn't seem that `GROUP BY t.r_id, t.hostname, t.a_tmstamp` will give that kind of result though..

Comment: Yes, I have the query and output in front of me. the above query is returning the given sample data.

Comment: @FanoFN they want only the record for each r_id/hostname with the latest a_tmstamp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fetch the row which has the Max value for a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can employ some trickery to get the status/message/m_id for the latest a_tmpstamp:

```
SELECT
   t.r_id,
   t.hostname,
   max(t.a_tmstamp) max_tmstamp,
   substr(max(concat(t.a_tmstamp,t.r_status)),24) as r_status,
   substr(max(concat(t.a_tmstamp,t.message)),24) as message,
   substr(max(concat(t.a_tmstamp,t.m_id)),24) as m_id
FROM (
SELECT
   audit.r_id as r_id,
   nhost.host_name as hostname,
   meta.r_status as r_status,   
   meta.step as step,
   meta.id as m_id,
   meta.message as message,
   audit.a_timestamp as a_tmstamp,
   npr.nas_provider as nas_provider             
FROM audit
   INNER JOIN npr ON npr.nr_id = audit.r_id
   AND audit.a_timestamp BETWEEN now() - interval 30 DAY AND now()
   INNER JOIN nhost ON audit.r_id = nhost.nr_id      
   INNER JOIN meta ON audit.audit_m_id = meta.id                                  
   INNER JOIN nprw ON npr.pw_id = nprw.id   
   AND nprw.ap_step = meta.step                
   WHERE meta.r_status regexp 'FAIL'
   ORDER BY  a_timestamp DESC
     ) AS t 
 GROUP BY t.r_id, t.hostname
 ORDER BY max_tmstamp DESC;
```

Comment: thanks a lot. what do you think about using `substring_index(group_concat(t.message order by t.a_tmstamp desc), ',', 1) as message,`?

Comment: doesn't work if message contains a comma or is longer than the group_concat_max_len setting (and gives a warning if it is too long); the timestamp is a fixed length, easier just to concat and then remove it.  I guess if you might change the type of the timestamp, you could use `length(max(t.a_tmstamp))+1` instead of 24